# How to access element from an array of objects returned from node in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting an array of objects in my `$http.get` request. I am doing the following:

```
$http.get("/showdata").then(function (response) {
    var thedata = response.data.category;
    console.log(thedata);
    $scope.alldata = response.data;
    if (thedata === "school") {
        $scope.category = "SchoolBC";
    } else {
        $scope.category = "Not School";
    }
});
```

How can i check something in the response and set the `$scope` accordingly?

What I get in return is:

```
[
    {
        id: "123456",
        category: "school",
        title: "first test" 
    },
    {
        id: "789012",
        category: "home",
        title: "second test"        
    }
]
```

In the frontend I have:

```
<ul ng-repeat = "mydata in alldata">
  <li>{{mydata.title}}<p>{{category}}</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's an array. So you access its first element using response.data[0], and its second element using response.data[1].

Comment: it is not clear what you're asking.. but it seems you need to use a for loop, or a forEach (asuming you have more data than just that)

Comment: How can I put a forEach loop inside a `$http.get` ?

Comment: Edited question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the answer based on comments and edit of your question. Loop through objects in array and override object property according to condition:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []); 
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    var thedata = [
    {
        id: "123456",
        category: "school",
        title: "first test" 
    },
    {
        id: "789012",
        category: "home",
        title: "second test"        
    },
    {
        id: "789012",
        category: ['home', 'school', 'primary', 'pre-primary', 'test', 'test1', 'test2' ],
        title: "third test"        
    }
];

    function overrideObjectValue(data) {
            
         angular.forEach(data , function(value, key){
         
             if(typeof value.category === 'object') {
             
                 if ($.inArray('school', value.category)) {
                     data[key].category = "SchoolBC";
                 } else {
                    data[key].category = "Not School";
                 } 
                 
             } else {

                 if (value.category === "school") {
                     data[key].category = "SchoolBC";
                 } else {
                    data[key].category = "Not School";
                 } 

             }   
         });
         return data;
    }
    
    $scope.alldata = overrideObjectValue(thedata);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat = "mydata in alldata">
    <li>{{mydata.title}}<p>{{mydata.category}}</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But how to get this with the `$scope`? Edited question. Please check

Comment: Do you mean only that specific object matching category "school"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All I want to do is to have a different `$scope.category` for the record that matched the category.

Comment: Can you please help me with the same for an array? if category is an array and I want to only find school from the array, how do I do it?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Especially at the third item in the 'thedata' object. I dont know how that object comes in your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138063/discussion-between-somename-and-yolo).